# Command won't run in the background from a shell script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to start the following command in a shell script and have it run in the background:

```bash
npx tailwindcss -i ./static/src/input.css -o ./static/src/output.css --watch &
```

It works in my shell, but as soon as I put it in a script, it won't run. If I take off the trailing `&` it will run in the script, but I need it in the background. Any idea why this particular command won't run in the background when being called from a shell script?

Comment: Hm, does your script possibly end before that program is finished running in the background?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, the program is supposed to watch for files, so I want it to keep running after my script ends.

Answer (score 0):

Your script runs in a shell started for the purpose of running your script. That shell will not exit before the last process it started has exited.

Solution: don't run your script - source it instead from your current shell. That however means that you need to keep that shell around for as long as the program rubs in the background.

The question really is, since you're running a command from an npm package and want to run it in the background, whether this wouldn't be a case for running things in a daemon process. In your case, node.js was written to do exactly that, daemonized execution of JavaScript.